# how to use the Background Worker in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, progress-bar, backgroundworker

i wants to use the BackgroundWorker in asp.net with ajax to get the data from the data base and export it into excel. when click the start button backgound worker will start load the data from database and write into excel when process complete that excel will download. these process show to use through Progress bar.

but problem in httpcontext(it may wrong), when click the start button excel file are created but it's not download. please fix the problem.
i given the code

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)   
        {
            _backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress=true;
            _backgroundWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            _backgroundWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(_backgroundWorker_DoWork);
            _backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(_backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged);
            _backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(_backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);              

        }

    protected void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            if (!_backgroundWorker.IsBusy)
            {
                _backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
            }

        }

        void _backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            string display = &quot;Message Pop-up!&quot;;
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), &quot;myalert&quot;, &quot;alert(&#39;&quot; + display + &quot;&#39;);&quot;, true);
        }

        void _backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {        
            ProgressBar1.SetProgress(e.ProgressPercentage);

        }

        void _backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {        
            Start(ProgressBar1.Progress, _httpContext);
        }

        private void Start(Progress progress, HttpContext context)
         {
            ProductBussiness productBussiness = new ProductBussiness();
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            Table htmltable=new Table();

            int Totalcount = productBussiness.GetCount();
            int page = Totalcount / 100;
            double progresPercent = 100.00 / page;
            for (int i = 1; i &lt;=page; i++)
            {
                 dataTable = productBussiness.GetProductData(i);
                 int percent=(int)(i * progresPercent);
                _backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(percent, progress);

                progress.SetProgress((i * progresPercent)/100);
                if(i&lt;=page)
                    ConvertToHtmlTable(dataTable, htmltable, builder, false, context);
                else
                    ConvertToHtmlTable(dataTable, htmltable, builder, true, context);

            }

        }

        #endregion           

        public StringBuilder ConvertToHtmlTable(DataTable dt, Table table, StringBuilder builder, bool end, HttpContext context)
          {
                   if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
                   {
                        return null;//`enter code here`
                   }

                   if (table != null)
                   {
                       foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
                       {
                           builder.Append(&quot;&lt;tr align=&#39;left&#39; valign=&#39;top&#39;&gt;&quot;);
                           foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
                           {
                               builder.Append(&quot;&lt;td align=&#39;left&#39; valign=&#39;top&#39;&gt;&quot;);
                               builder.Append(r[c.ColumnName]);
                               builder.Append(&quot;&lt;/td&gt;&quot;);
                           }
                           builder.Append(&quot;&lt;/tr&gt;&quot;);
                       }
                   }
                   if (end)
                   {
                       context.Response.Clear();
                       StringBuilder str1 = new StringBuilder();

                       str1.Append(&quot;&lt;html&gt;&quot;);
                       str1.Append(&quot;&lt;head&gt;&quot;);
                       str1.Append(&quot;&lt;title&gt;&quot;);
                       str1.Append(&quot;Page-&quot;);
                       str1.Append(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
                       str1.Append(&quot;&lt;/title&gt;&quot;);
                       str1.Append(&quot;&lt;/head&gt;&quot;);
                       str1.Append(&quot;&lt;body&gt;&quot;);
                       str1.Append(&quot;&lt;table border=&#39;1px&#39; cellpadding=&#39;5&#39; cellspacing=&#39;0&#39; &quot;);
                       str1.Append(&quot;style=&#39;border: solid 1px Silver; font-size: x-small;&#39;&gt;&quot;);
                       str1.Append(&quot;&lt;th align=&#39;left&#39; valign=&#39;top&#39;&gt;&quot;);
                       foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
                       {
                           str1.Append(&quot;&lt;td align=&#39;left&#39; valign=&#39;top&#39;&gt;&lt;b&gt;&quot;);
                           str1.Append(c.ColumnName);
                           str1.Append(&quot;&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&quot;);
                       }
                       str1.Append(&quot;&lt;/tr&gt;&quot;);

                       str1.Append(builder);

                       str1.Append(&quot;&lt;/table&gt;&quot;);
                       str1.Append(&quot;&lt;/body&gt;&quot;);
                       str1.Append(&quot;&lt;/html&gt;&quot;);

                      context.Response.ClearContent();
                      context.Response.ClearHeaders();
                      context.Response.BufferOutput = true;

                      context.Response.AddHeader(&quot;content-disposition&quot;, &quot;attachment;filename=ExportData1.xls&quot;);
                      context.Response.Charset = &quot;&quot;;
                      context.Response.ContentType = &quot;application/vnd.xls&quot;;
                      context.Response.Write(str1);
                      // Response.Flush();
                      // Response.Close();
                      context.Response.End();

                   }

                return builder;
           }
```

thank you
Pandiyan

Comment: You are mixing client and server concerns... How can the server inform the client of these updates? You need to look at some communication mechanism (SignalR or similar) or the client can poll for status updates but as it stands this won't work.

Comment: _"how to use the Background Worker in ASP.Net?"_  - use it NOT.

Comment: The BackgroundWorker is  intended for WinForms and WPF, you have no use for it and it only confuses. The Completed event will run on a Page object that's already dead and forgotten.